# When debt to GDP is only around 85%, how can this article quote as 300%?

Tags: gdp, government-debt, debt

I was reading an article in FT, where debt to GDP is quoted as 300% for US and Japan. However, all the official sites for US quotes the debt to GDP as 85% for US.

This article is from a reputed investment banker in Wall Street. Can someone explain?
Link:

[Economic Trends 2022](https://on.ft.com/31p32aL)

From the article:
**Twenty-five countries including the US and China have total debt above 300 per cent of GDP,**

Comment: Total debt, not government debt. There is no source, so hard to say what is used exactly. It's above 300, not at 300. https://www.ceicdata.com/en/indicator/united-states/total-debt--of-gdp for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the FT article is talking about total debt.

For Q3 2021, US federal government debt alone was 122% of GDP. Source: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/GFDEGDQ188S

For Q2 2021, US household debt was 78% of GDP. Source: https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/HDTGPDUSQ163N

To get total debt you would also need to add the debt of corporations and state and local governments. The total being over 300% seems very likely.

Comment: Thanks a lot James. Appreciate it.